# Difference between $\triangleq$, $:=$, $=$ and $\equiv$ when defining a function

Tags: notation

Which of the following notation is a correct definition of the square function?

1. $f(x) \triangleq x^2$
2. $f(x) := x^2$
3. $f(x) = x^2$
4. $f(x) \equiv x^2$

While this question is similar to [The meaning of various equality symbols](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269958), the aforementioned question and its answers do not address the usage if these symbols in the context of function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Different authors use different conventions. Unless you have a particular reason you need to do something fancier, just write $f(x)=x^2$ -- that's what the vast majority of written mathematics does.

Comment: $=$ my get confusing when defining predicates as in $P(x) = (x=0)$.

Comment: @Robbo: Mathematical notation does not usually use $=$ between things that have _truth values_ (rather than denote objects). So one would typically write that definition as $P(x)\Leftrightarrow x=0$ or $P(x)\equiv x=0$. Not because it's a definition (though some authors _also_ use $\equiv$ for definitions), but because it's asserting that two propositions have the same truth value, not that two expressions evaluate to the same object.